# How to from Graph API what the extended permissions are for my Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a bunch of access tokens for my facebook applications. Can anyone tell me if there is a process where I can know what extended permissions I have used during the authorization prcess. ie during the token creation process.

I could find noting like that using Graph API. I hope u understand this question. Thank you for any help.

-D

Answer (score 0):

You could use extended permissions "offline_access", but you will still need to save the token for the user.  See docs http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions